# How to loop through a python list in batch?

Tags: python, list

A file contains 10000 lines with one entry in each line. I need to process the file but in batches (small chunks).

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")
data = file.readlines()
file.close()

total_count = len(data) # equals to ~10000 or less
max_batch = 50 # loop through 'data' with 50 entries at max in each loop.

for i in range(total_count):
     batch = data[i:i+50] # first 50 entries
     result = process_data(batch) # some time consuming processing on 50 entries
     if result == True:
           # add to DB that 50 entries are processed successfully!
     else:
           return 0 # quit the operation
           # later start again from the point it failed.
           # say 51st or 2560th or 9950th entry
```

What to do here so that next loop picks entries from 51 to 100th item and so on?

If somehow the operation is not successful and breaks in-between, then need to start loop again only from the batch where it failed (based on DB entry).

I'm not able to code a proper logic. Should I keep two lists? Or anything else?

Comment: `range(0, total_count, 50)`

Comment: your entry range needs to be [i*50:(i+1)*50], also why wait for a batch to complete - you could make process_data into a thread - take a look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are close.

```
chunks = (total_count - 1) // 50 + 1
for i in range(chunks):
     batch = data[i*50:(i+1)*50]
```

Comment: It seems to be an incorrect solution if you do not want any empty batches when `total_count % 50 == 0`. The number of chunks should be `(total_count - 1) // 50 + 1`.

Comment: @AndersTornkvist: nice catch! Edited.

Answer (score 37):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
batch_size = 3    

for i in range(0, len(l), batch_size):
    print(l[i:i+batch_size])
    # more logic here

>>> [1,2,3]
>>> [4,5,6]
>>> [7,8,9]
>>> [10]
```

I think this is the most straight-forward and readable approach. If you need to retry a certain batch, you can retry inside the loop (serial) or you can open a thread per batch - depends on the application...

Answer (score 6):

```
def chunk_list(datas, chunksize):
    """Split list into the chucks

    Params:
        datas     (list): data that want to split into the chunk
        chunksize (int) : how much maximum data in each chunks

    Returns:
        chunks (obj): the chunk of list
    """

    for i in range(0, len(datas), chunksize):
        yield datas[i:i + chunksize]
```

ref: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+function+to+split+lists+into+batches

Answer (score 4):

With python 3.12 you can use `itertools.batched` ([the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched)):

```py
for batch in itertools.batched(data, 50):
    result = process_data(batch) # some time consuming processing on 50 entries
    if result == True:
          # add to DB that 50 entries are processed successfully!
    else:
          return 0 # quit the operation
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of `funcy`. This function will break your list into chunks for you: https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/seqs.html#chunks